# Ho to set the zero flag with lldb?

Tags: lldb, eflags

Is there a way to set the zero flag with the lldb debugger?

something like `set ($eflags)=` from gdb
there only seems to be `register write rflags ...` to set all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to set the zero flag in lldb:

```
(lldb) register write rflags `$rflags|0x40`
```

Comment: how do you unset it?

Comment: Found it: `register write rflags `$rflags ^ 0x40`` is a way to do it

Answer (score 2):

## Toggle ZF flag in ***gdb-pda***

[image: Screenshot while toggling ZF flag]

```
gdb-peda$ set $eflags = 0x296 
gdb-peda$ p $eflags
$1 = [ PF AF SF IF ]
gdb-peda$ set $eflags = $eflags ^ 0x40
gdb-peda$ p $eflags
$2 = [ PF AF ZF SF IF ]
```